# Summation on muscles

Tags: physiology, muscles

I am learning myology and encountered 2 problems in tetanus and summation:

1. Unfused tetanus is just a **continual summation of twitches** if I am not mistaken. However, is it a **MUST** for summation / unfused tetanus to constantly increasing muscle tension from the photo (the graph) i.e. is this the definition?

Since we are in unfused tetanus when we hold something, and I can’t feel my biceps are constantly increasing in contraction / tension. (to my understanding, complete tetanus is when we are lifting up very heavy things only as it utilizes too much ATP)
[image]

2. Can I say the muscles are in tetanus during contracting (**lifting**), and also in tetanus during constantly contracted state (**keep the thing holding up**) Since tetanus is just a frequent action of sliding filaments, which is common in both actions?

Also, during tetanus, I don’t need to shorten my muscles anymore (just holding something still), but myosin heads are still power-stroking to shorten the sarcomere/muscle, may I ask how to explain this?

Thank you very much.